# Google Chrome new tab page thumbnails no longer fit and wrap out of view

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

For the past week (quite possibly following an update?) I've noticed that the thumbnails of frequently visited pages on the Google Chrome new tab page no longer fit and wrap out of view!

Previously there were 2 rows of 4 thumbnails. Now I have 2 rows of 3 thumbnails and you can just see the very top of the missing 2 thumbnails on a 3rd row!

[image: Google Chrome New Tab page]

Browser cache is clear.

I can use the Object Inspector to reduce the width of the thumbnail container (an anchor with class `mv-tile`) by 1px and the thumbnails instantly go back to their correct positions (2 x 4). But this obviously does not "stick".

What's gone wrong with the "new tab page" stylesheet? (I've not found anyone else reporting the same problem.)

How do I make this fix permanent?

Chrome version 44.0.2403.130 m (which Chrome reports is "up to date").

Comment: mine looks perfectly fine. Did you reset it ?

Comment: I have a funny feeling this is unique to me, but not sure how - other than Chrome's "quirkiness". What do you mean by "reset"? The browser has been restarted and the PC rebooted several times since this started. I should have said (for completeness)... I'm on version 44.0.2403.130 m (which Chrome reports is "up to date").

Comment: I mean **reset chrome**

Comment: Right, gotcha. Didn't know there was that option! No, I have not "reset it". But I don't really want to "reset it" at the current time... got too many tabs I want to keep open, cookies, extensions and not to mention the frequently visited pages.

Comment: There is another way you can test it. Rename the existing google chrome profile and create another one. If it doesn't work you can always delete the new profile else your choice. Either reset or move to new profile

Comment: You are not alone. I have it too. Does this help? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522834

Comment: @clsturgeon Thanks for that! And amazingly, after a few comments on that other thread it's suddenly fixed! Didn't even have to restart Chrome! Is it fixed for you? If so you can post "something to that effect" as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are not alone. I had the issue. As suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522834)  it was a css issue and appears to have been corrected.

However, prior to the issue I used to see a couple links in the upper right (one being gmail). These links have not reappeared.

Comment: Yes, I see the same - whilst I have the 8 thumbnails back, I no longer see the links in the top right either.

Comment: Miraculously, the links in the top right corner have suddenly reappeared! They were missing this morning and they are back this afternoon - and I've not even restarted Chrome! (?)

Comment: Actually it hasn't been corrected yet. Some users have reported that at a certain point the bug seemed to be fixed without doing anything, but then it has shown up again. And officially the bug is still open.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually caused the phenomenon by accident with a hand gesture on the touchpad of my MacBook Pro. The page got zoomed in to about 150%.

You can reproduce the phenomenon by clicking on the "three bar" menu and increasing the zoom.  Then decrease back to 100% and it goes back to normal.

Comment: Admittedly I'm on a different platform, but I had tried zooming the page (to try and resolve the problem), but this changed nothing. Although "the problem" I was seeing was an actual change to the CSS on the page, which wouldn't be caused by zooming on the client-side?

Comment: Yeah. I didn't see the aspect about the links going away. That definitely would not have been effected by the zoom.  I was able to reproduce the tabs going from rows of 4 to rows of 3 with my daughter's chrome book by changing resolution. But that's by css design, not a bug like what you experienced.